# Calculating elements of the $\mathbb{Z}^2/\!\ker\varphi$ group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

If I know that $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to S_{15}$ is the homomorphism defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\varphi(1,0)&=(2,7,3)(3,11,5)(12,13)\\
\varphi(0,1)&=(14,15)(1,4,6,8,9,10)
\end{align}
I was asked to calculate how many elements $\mathbb{Z}^2/\!\ker\varphi$ has.

Is it true to say that from the first homomorphism theorem we get $\mathbb{Z}^2/\!\ker\varphi \cong S_{15}$. So from $|S_{15}|=15!$ we can understand that $\mathbb{Z}^2/\!\ker\varphi$ has $15!$ elements. For some reason, it is written in the textbook that is has only $60$ elements. Why is that?

Comment: $\Bbb Z^2/\ker\varphi$ is isomorphic to the _image_ of $\varphi$, not necessarily the whole codomain.

Comment: To apply the homomorphism theorem the map should be an epimorphism

Comment: isn't $\varphi$ surjective so $Im\varphi = S_{15}$. If not, how to count the elements then?

Comment: All the comments above are true, but also, it seems, $60$ is wrong, too.

Comment: In the image of $\varphi$, the permutations only send $14$ to $15$ or $14$ to $14.$ So the image of $\varphi$ is not all of $S_{15}.$

Comment: Also, the image of an abelian group under an homomorphism is always abelian, so the image of $\mathbb Z^2$ is abelian, and all of $S_{15}$ is not abelian.

Comment: so how to count the elements?

Comment: @abuka123: You need to figure out what the image is.

Answer (score 1):

Set, for simplicity, $\sigma=\varphi(1,0)$ and $\tau=\varphi(0,1)$. Then
$$
\sigma=(2,7,3,11,5)(12,13)
$$
and so $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint, so $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$ and the homomorphism is indeed well defined.

The image of $\varphi$ is an abelian subgroup of $S_{15}$, so it certainly isn't the whole $S_{15}$.

Set, for simplicity, $\sigma=\varphi(1,0)$ and $\tau=\varphi(0,1)$. Then
$$
\varphi(m,n)=\sigma^m\tau^n
$$
and so the image of $\varphi$ is the subgroup generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$. Now you should be able to finish, using the fact that there is an obvious surjective homomorphism
$$
\langle\sigma\rangle\times\langle\tau\rangle\to
\langle\sigma\rangle\langle\tau\rangle=\operatorname{im}\varphi
$$
What's the kernel of this homomorphism?

Comment: $(2,7,3)(3,11,5)$ aren't disjoint

Comment: @janmarqz I meant $\sigma$ and $\tau$, but I have clarified.

Comment: your explaination is certainly true and I would upvote you if you criticized positively and upvote mine, greets!

Answer (score 0):

To apply the homomorphism theorem the map should be an epimorphism.

In the other hand to count how many elements in the image are, you just got to see is the orders of $\varphi(1,0)=(2,7,3,11,5)(12,13)$ and $\varphi(0,1)$ which happen to be ten and six respectively. Then $|{\rm im}\varphi|$ is $60$.

**Update:**

The next calculations might help you to understand
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(2,0)&=&((2,7,3,11,5)(12,13))^2,\\
&=&(2,3,5,7,11).\\
&&\\
\varphi(3,0)&=&((2,7,3,11,5)(12,13))^3,\\
&=&(2,11,7,5,3)(12,13).\\
&&\\
\varphi(4,0)&=&(2,5,11,3,7).\\
&&\\
\varphi(5,0)&=&(12,13).\\
&&\\
&...&\\
&&\\
\varphi(10,0)&=&e.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: $\phi(1,0)$ only has order $4$ (the "$3$" in the formula for $\phi(1,0)$ occurs twice).

Comment: ah! yes I'll correct

Comment: why calculating $o(\varphi(1,0))$ and $o(\varphi(0,1))$ gives the solution?

Comment: @abuka123: The image must be abelian and generated by $\varphi(1,0)$ and $\varphi(0,1)$. So the size of the image is equal to $|\langle \varphi(1,0)\rangle||\langle \varphi(0,1)\rangle|/|\langle\varphi(1,0)\rangle\cap\langle \varphi(0,1)\rangle|$.

Comment: Observe that $\text {Im} (\varphi)$ is generated by $\varphi (1,0)$ and $\varphi(0,1)$ since $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ generate $\Bbb Z^2.$

Comment: Also observe that the elements of a finite group $G$ generated by $a,b \in G$ are of the form $a^ib^j$ where $0 \leq i \leq n$ and $0 \leq j \leq m$ where $o(a)=n$ and $o(b)=m.$ But then $|G| = mn.$